# What's this "Jl. Sg." appended to a name in the Social Register?

Tags: history, abbreviations, north-american-english

Screenshotted from the (fictitious) "1929 Social Register" in the opening sequence of the film [*Down to Their Last Yacht*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_to_Their_Last_Yacht) (1934).

[image: Colt-Stratton, Miss Linda Jl. Sg.]

"Miss Linda Colt-Stratton" I get, but what's the "Jl. Sg." after her name?

My impression from some very cursory Google-Booksing is that typically the Social Register would contain earned titles such as degrees ("M.Sc.", "Ph.D.") or I suppose military ranks, but even if Miss Linda Colt-Stratton *were* a sergeant, I still don't understand the "Jl." part. Vice versa, I've found ["Jl." used as an abbreviation of "July" in one place](https://books.google.com/books?id=9rhCAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=Jl), but I don't see how that would explain anything, either.

Theories which additionally explain Mrs Geoffrey Colt-Stratton's "Cda." suffix will earn bonus points. :)

Comment: Odd that they'd abbreviate Frederick and then fill the unused space with dots. Does that tell us he prefers "Fred"?

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviations are almost certainly club references or academic affiliations.  I'd go with "Junior League" for Jl, but it would be a guess. Sg. could be local to wherever this SR is from, or it could be made up, seeing as how this is a fictitious register.  Cda appears to be Colonial Dames of America. Google has published the [1909 NYC Social Register](https://archive.org/stream/socialregistern05usgoog/socialregistern05usgoog_djvu.txt), and the abbreviations used in it, including Cda, are listed at the beginning.